# Match and get value from one Excel file to another Excel file in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have two excel files, I'll name them: **source.xlsx**, **output.xlsx**.

I need to match the data using *Caller ID* column of **source.xlsx** to *svc_no* column of **output.xlsx**

If there is not a match or the value is 'NULL' using the *Caller ID* column, I can use the *adsl* column of **source.xlsx** to match with *port* column of **output.xlsx**.

If there is a match, then I should ignore the *port* and write the *Caller ID*

The data in **source.xlsx** looks like this:

```
Caller ID    adsl    Comparison Result
NULL         2/12    Not Match
11111111     2/267   Match
22222222     4/243   Match
22222222     2/117   Possible Match
```

The data in **output.xlsx** looks like this:

```
svc_no              Caller ID    port    Comparison Result  
22222222                         4/243  
11111111                         2/267      
22222222                         2/117
NULL                             2/12
```

My expected output would be to write the data from **source.xlsx** to **output.xlsx**:

```
svc_no              Caller ID    port    Comparison Result
22222222            22222222     4/243   Match
11111111            11111111     2/267   Match
22222222            22222222     2/117   Possible Match 
NULL                NULL         2/12    Not Match
```

I tried using:

```
df = read_excel('source.xlsx')
df1 = read_excel('output.xlsx')

df = df['Caller ID'].isin(df1['svc_no'])]
df['Caller ID'] = df1['Caller ID']

df1.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

But it does not match and write randomly.

Comment: Joining on `source.Caller ID` and `output.svc_no` will generate duplicated rows for `22222222            22222222     4/243` and `22222222  22222222  2/117` because it ignores the `Comparison Result` column. Which rows should be picked?

Comment: @ DeepSpace each 22222222 should still have separate rows as they have different adsl/port

Comment: That's not what I meant. Each one will have duplicated rows based on the `Comparison Result` column, ie `NULL      NULL   2/12         Not Match  ;  
11111111  11111111  2/267             Match  ;  
22222222  22222222  4/243             Match  ;  
22222222  22222222  2/117             Match  ;  
22222222  22222222  4/243    Possible Match   ;  
22222222  22222222  2/117    Possible Match`

Comment: I see. The Comparison Result is just copied along to wherever row it is.

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Comment: @jpp Hi, the requirements have changed. I will update my question as soon as I grasp the new requirements. I have also reviewed your answer. I wasn't able to apply it to my code yet but I will update. Thanks

Comment: @RickyAguilar, If it's a new question, please ask as a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). The current question may help others who have a similar problem.

Comment: @jpp Got it. Thank you.

Comment: @RickyAguilar, If you have time, feel free to also give feedback (accept, upvote, comment) on the answer to this one. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is one way.

```
# filter output for 2 pre-populated columns
output = output[['svc_no', 'port']]

# add duplicate column
output['Caller ID'] = output['svc_no']

# create series mapping from source
s = source.set_index(['Caller ID', 'adsl'])['Comparison Result']

# map series to output
output['Comparison Result'] = output.set_index(['svc_no','port']).index.map(s.get)

print(output)

        svc_no   port    Caller ID Comparison Result
0  2.22222e+07  4/243  2.22222e+07             Match
1  1.11111e+07  2/267  1.11111e+07             Match
2  2.22222e+07  2/117  2.22222e+07     PossibleMatch
3         NULL   2/12         NULL          NotMatch
```